# VSCode displays 'Installing Kotlin Language Server' for a long time. Can I stop it?

Tags: kotlin, visual-studio-code, language-server-protocol

VScode displays this status when I open it:

[image]

> Installing Kotlin Language Server...

It takes a long time to go away. It also seems to make it impossible for me to debug my Android projects.

How can I know how long it will take to complete?

Is it possible and safe to cancel the operation?

I don't believe I use Kotlin in my projects, so I don't think I need it.

#### update:

Restart computer not solve this. it still become Installing.

Is it possible to show progress (like percent: 20%) ? I waiting for a while now, but I don't know when it can be finished.

Comment: Restart computer not solve this. it still become Installing.

Comment: It is key to learn which extension is downloading that language server. Then you have to report the issue to the developer(s). There is no obvious fix for such.

Comment: I just want to debug flutter project, which didn't include Kotlin code.

Comment: @LexLi  you are right, I disable Kotlin extension, and it finally stopped,  Thank you for saving my tiime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me made Disable the Kotlin extension in vscode make the error go away :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

download https://github.com/fwcd/kotlin-language-server/releases and unzip set

```
"kotlin.languageServer.path": "D:\\work\\001vbox\\server\\bin\\kotlin-language-server.bat"
```